# Why does my rsync server on windows always set the read-only flag when I write to it?

Tags: windows, rsync, read-only

I'm using cwrsync on windows. This is my daemon config file

```
use chroot = false
strict modes = false
hosts allow = *
log file = rsyncd.log
pid file = rsyncd.pid
port = 11011

# Module definitions
# Remember cygwin naming conventions : c:\work becomes /cygdrive/c/work
#

[read]
path = /cygdrive/o/MBackupData/out/
read only = true
transfer logging = yes
list = true
timeout = 30

[write]
path = /cygdrive/o/MBackupData/in/
read only = false
write only = false
transfer logging = yes
list = true
timeout = 30
refuse options = delete
```

The modules all point to a ntfs partition. I'm using this command to write files to it:

```
bin\rsync -v --append --perms --remove-source-files --partial --modify-window=1 -z --compress-level=9 --progress --times --stats --links --port=11011 /cygdrive/o/MBackupData/out/*.* 192.168.1.5::write/
```

It works, but for some reason, all the files have the read-only flag set. The source files don't have that flag. How can I configure it to not set that flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is needed, but it works for me. I'ld classify this as a workaround though.

Adding

```
--chmod=a=rw,Da+x
```

to the clients parameters list removes the read-only flag on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you setup cwRsync for [not to process permissions](https://www.itefix.no/i2/content/permissions-filesdirectories-are-clutteredmixed) at client side, and remove **--perms** from your command line. It has no meaning for windows-based operations.

If you want to transfer permission or alike, you may consider to take an additional step described [here](https://www.itefix.no/i2/content/can-rsync-transfer-securityownership-information-between-two-windows-machines).